# How to navigate to a modal component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-material, modal-dialog

I have a Edit Button on my **SearchComponent** that send the user to my **EditFormComponent** page through a *navigateByUrl('url-link')*, but I would like to keep the user on the **SearchComponent** page and open a **Modal** component that have the **EditFormComponent** inside of it.

I'm using Angular Material Design to create the **Modal** component, and then I called the **EditFormComponent** inside of it but the Modal pop up without the data loaded from the **SearchComponent** and the 'background' loads the **EditFormComponent** page, leaving the Modal component empty.
Here is my code:
**SEARCH.COMPONENT.TS**

```
export class DistributionFormComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() dataModal: DistributionSearchModalComponent;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log('data coming from modal', this.dataModal);
}

editDistribution(id) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(`/registry/basic/distribution/edit/${id}`);
}

openModal(id) {
      this.dialog.open(DistributionSearchModalComponent, {
        width: '660px',
        height: '760px',
        data: {
          id: id.id,
          address: id.address,
          service: id.service,
        }
      })
 }
```

**MODAL.COMPONENT.HTML**

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" class="pt-1 pr-1 pl-1">
    <div fxFlex="95" fxLayoutAlign="start">
        <h1 matDialogTitle>Edit</h1>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="5" fxLayoutAlign="end">
    </div>
</div>
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" class="pt-1 pr-1 pl-1">
    <op-distribution-form [dataModal]="dataForm"></op-distribution-form>
</div>
```

**MODAL.COMPONENT.TS**

```
export class DistributionSearchModalComponent implements OnInit {
    dataForm = this.data;
    providerForm: FormGroup;
    distributionForm: FormGroup;
 
    constructor(
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DistributionSearchModalComponent>,
        public confirmService: AppConfirmService,
        public fb: FormBuilder,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('MODAL DATA ', this.data);
 }
```

**FORM.COMPONENT.TS**

```
export class DistributionFormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() dataModal: DistributionSearchModalComponent;
    objModal;
    searchId;

    constructor(
        private dialog: MatDialog,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.buildItemForm();
        this.distributionForm.controls.distribuicao.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            this.itemsSubject$.next(value);
        });
        this.hasPermission = this.permissionsServices.hasPermission('distribution');

        console.log('data coming from modal ', this.dataModal)
        this.objModal = this.dataModal;
        console.log('modal id ', this.objModal.id)        
    }
```

Comment: Can you please attach your current output? It may help other to better understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the modal component, you do not need the navigateByUrl anymore. Simply call openModal onClick of the edit button.

To ensure that the modal opens correctly, you can also make sure that DistributionSearchModalComponent is injected into your entryComponents within your app.module.ts.

Additionally, inside your modal.component.ts. you are initializing dataForm to this.data, but the dialog data has not been instantiated yet in the constructor.

Let me know if any additional insight might be needed!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it really helps.
I can't remove the navigateByUrl because I need both the modal and the edit button. I need to replicate the behavior of the edit button that loads all the data on inputs when the page loads in the modal component, but I'm having problem with binding the data coming from modal in the inputs.